# Powershell | CSV Export; local admins

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have tried to search all local administrators from all computers in the AD and now fail at the csv export.

script:

```
function get-localadmins{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
  [string]$computerName
  )
  $group = get-wmiobject win32_group -ComputerName $computerName -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'" 
  $query = "GroupComponent = `"Win32_Group.Domain='$($group.domain)'`,Name='$($group.name)'`"" 
  $list = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -ComputerName $computerName -Filter $query
  $list | ForEach{$_.PartComponent} | ForEach{$_.substring($_.lastindexof("Domain=") + 7).replace("`",Name=`"","\")}
}

foreach($computer in (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=XXX,OU=Computers,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=dom' | select name).name){
Write-Verbose "Checking $computer" -Verbose
get-localadmins -computerName $computer 
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? also, i dont see the part where you export this as a csv? is this all the code?

Comment: You're `.Replace()` call in syntactically incorrect. Also, you shouldn't need 2 `Foreach-Object` commands as one should suffice, not just for cleaner code, but for a slight performance increase; sending anything down the pipeline can slow down your execution quite a bit.

Comment: Why not use `Get-LocalGroupMember`?